# How can I select distinct names and with their corresponding earliest detected time in django orm?

Tags: python, django

Im really having a difficult time querying my model in django orm. I need to create a query where it will select distinct names with their corresponding earliest time detected. Any help or advice would be very appreciated.
Note that the real table has hundreds of entries this is only a simple representation.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DtSo.png)
Ps. Im just new here, i dont know how to show the image properly. Sorry

Comment: posting images usually doesnt go over well ...

Answer (score 0):

`MyModel.objects.order_by('timestamp').distinct('name')`

I think would work?

Comment: This gave me an idea. Thank you